# REST Web Service client with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, rest

i'm posting my first question cause i'm stuck with this problem trying to call a REST web service with jQuery.
Here my code :

```
<script>
    $("#selListSub").change(function() {
        var listid = $("#selListSub option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            beforeSend : function() {
                headers = {
                    'Authorization' : 'myKey'
                };
            },
            url : "https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/lists/" + listid + "/customfields.json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");               
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I retrieve the option selected in my < select > then use it to call the ws.

I looked for and try every solution i've found on this site but nothing worked. I've tested the url with the Auth header on Postman and it works fine.

The web service is supposed to return a json object but the first thing i would like to achieve is to reach the success function...

I don't know if it can help but here's the equivalent of what I want to do in java/jersey (this works) :

```
String idList = request.getParameter("selListSub");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget resourceTarget = client.target("https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/lists/" + idList + "/customfields.json");
String jsonInString = resourceTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("Authorization", "myKey").get(String.class);
```

If someone see where's my mistake, please tell me ; )

Regards.

Comment: Do you get authentication error or something else in response? Have you checked request and/or response of your request in chrome dev tools network tab? Request should match the request you give in postman, if it doesn't you should have a clue there.

Comment: @IsmailS I don't think that it's an authentication problem cause i'm using this api in my java program and it works fine.  I'm using this : String jsonInStringDelete=target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("Authorization","myKey").post(Entity.entity(stringaddfieldtojson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), String.class);   The thing is that i have to use ajax to solve my problem so i have to find how to do the same thing but in jQuery.

Comment: As you seem to know a lot about jQuery, and you don't see major mistake in the code i pasted, i guess there's something else i did wrong in my app...

Comment: Did you tried looking at request details in network tab of chrome dev tools or firebug (depends on what you use)?

Comment: I'm trying it right now but don't know what to infer from what i'm reading, everything seems ok...

Comment: Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate

Comment: Accept-Language 
fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Comment: Authorization 
myKey

Comment: that was for the request

Comment: and for the response : Content-Type 
application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Can you add to question, snapshot/image of what you can see in PostMan request details and what you can see in chrome dev tools request?

Comment: I need to up my reputation then i'll post the snapshots, thanks for your time btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wan't to change beforeSend function as below

```
<script>
    $("#selListSub").change(function() {
        var listid = $("#selListSub option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'myKey');
            },
            url : "https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/lists/" + listid + "/customfields.json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");               
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
you might also want to do below in your beforeSend function

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried your synthaxe before but the call didn't reach success either. I'm keeping your synthaxe and i still try to solve my problem.

Comment: I was wondering if i could get a message error in the consoel so i've added this : error: function(e) {console.log(e);}  , but i don't see any message in the console, is it possible that the fonction neither passes in the success or the error path?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had missed to specify `xhr` parameter in `beforeSend` function. Now corrected. You might want to give it a go again.